# Facebook's ads api exception 294 - Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

My campaign is running on FB and I want to extract daily data with the help of Ads API.

I'm using facebook ads api and I'm facing this problem every time

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 294
   }
}
```

I have created one app `XYZ` and using this created I created an ad campaign.

With **Graph API Explorer** I generated **Access Token.** and I give permissions also.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find anything ? By the way i am the additional user. i wonder is this cause to this problem ?

Comment: No :( I didn't find any.

Comment: i found but lost 4 points.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891899/how-can-i-make-my-facebook-app-whitelisted

Answer (score 12):

You have to make sure you have an application white listed to use the Ads API.  Also, you need to make sure you get an access token for that white listed application.  If your app is white listed, you can use the graph explorer, change the drop down to your app, click get access token and make sure you tick the ads_management permissions.  Hope that helps.

Comment: How did you get your app white listed?

Comment: Here are two useful URLs for you:  https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access/  That talks about PMDs as well as whit listing.  The form to fill out to get your app white listed is at this direct link: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494 -  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: @Eric Brown do you know how long does it take FB to whitelist? It says 3 weeks on the form page..

Comment: @peipei: I'm not sure to be honest.  Though given we just got out of the holidays, I would expect you should hear something soon.  Good luck!

Comment: @EricBrown this link facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494 make your application white listed ?

Comment: @peipei does the link facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494 make your application white listed

Comment: @Fawad Ghafoor yes. that's the link.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to extended permission for accessing facebook ads using api.
In your facebook application which one you created in facebook account .Add itme in status and review for ads_managemnt, insight.

Setting -> Status & Review -> Items in Review.

Answer (score -1):

There are few way how to generate app access tokens in FB. If you want to access marketing api you should do this in page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/marketing-api/tools/ using required options.