# facebook ads_management always return error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I always get this thing when I do test in facebook API graph explorer

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#294) ", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 294
  }
}
```

What I did is GET https://graph.facebook.com/act_MY_ACC_ID , I already set permission for ads_management. This is also happen when I do test on my test code.

Comment: Is your app whitelisted for access to the ads api? Has your user actually granted your app that permission? passing the access token into [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will show you the permissions associated with that access token

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431746/facebooks-ads-api-exception-294-managing-advertisements-requires-the-extended says you need to have whitelisted the app in the Ads API too

Comment: App ID: 546863328683549 : Campaign Ads
User ID: 1779505246
Issued: 1373556241 (3 hours ago)
Expires: 1378740241 (in about 2 months)
Valid: True
Origin: Web
Scopes: ads_management
 - 
This is the return in debug tool

Comment: OK, that's a good start, but are you accessing one of that user's accounts or one they don't have access to?

Comment: The user's account has the access on campaign ads, i'm not sure on the `whitelisted` thing, is that the ip whitelist?

Answer (score 1):

Your app has to be whitelisted for ads api access.

If your app is whitelisted, you need to use a valid user access token to access the ads api endpoints. That user has to have given your app the ads_management permission and must also have access to the ads account you're trying to access.

Comment: Here is the link to request whitelisting https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494