# Need to be whitelisted on FB for Ads API even if my app is not public (is in development mode)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have a testing app and its in development mode and not available to the public. I just need to test the Ads API on Graph explorer. Should my IP needs to be whitelisted?
I red more post for making whitelist using following link,
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494

But Sandbox mode need the IP whitelisted for FB Ads api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook's ads api exception 294 - Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads\_management, and a participating API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431746/facebooks-ads-api-exception-294-managing-advertisements-requires-the-extended)

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook Ads API is restricted at an app level and is not dependent on whether the app is in development mode or not.